# Is There A Way to have Struts 2 Resource Bundle Point to a File Location?

Tags: struts2

I currently have a package on my class path called MyResources with multiple property files that struts uses.  Works great:

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="com.company.MyResources"/>
```

I am trying to move the properties files to a file location, so they can be updated without having to rebuild the package.  Is it possible in Struts 2 to refer to this file location?

For example, my new file location with the properties files is:

```
/g01/properties/
```

And I would like Struts to use that location for the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by providing an implementation of `ResourceBundleTextProvider` and initializing it in your `struts.xml` configuration file.

The default implementation, `com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProviderSupport` defers the text lookup to `com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil`.

There are a number of ways to go about this, but if you don't need *any* of the default S2 behavior, here's the place to start:

```
<bean type="com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider" name="struts" 
      class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProviderSupport" scope="default" />
```

Provide your own `ResourceBundleTextProvider` implementation that uses whatever configuration management you want, for example, we implemented a DB-backed version (with caching, of course) that allowed translations to live in, and be managed by, a normal DB and I18N front end.

I'll see if I can dig up my original work this weekend and provide a link to a stripped-down solution.

Comment: I managed to get Struts to point to my properties file, but I am having trouble getting the locale to my custom ResourceBundle.  Any advice? I am wondering if I should have a custom newBundle method...

Comment: @Kraagenskul You should be able to get it from `ActionContext.getContext()` IIRC, but I haven't had a chance to dig this stuff out yet, sorry.

Comment: That did the trick. Everything is working. Now to set up caching. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the file cannot be off the class path when you run your app. You should determine which classloader is used to load the resource. Then you should find a way to configure this classloader to be able to use the location as resource. So, it's possible. A short answer.